# Help to identify a SOT23-5/SOT26 component

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, code

I'm looking for some help to identify a SOT23-5 component that has the marking code *D72* on it.

The chip is located on a Canon camera mother board.
There are 4 chips with the same marking code.
One of them was ripped off the PCB when the camera fell down.

[image]

Comment: What’s the outer dimensions of the plastic body? Solder it back?

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching in Google I found that ROHM is the manufacturer for this component and I also found that the full part number is [EMD72](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/digital/emd72t2r-e.pdf).

Hope this information will be helpful to other.

Comment: Please *accept* this answer so that your question can be marked as resolved.